# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -- Not understanding issue

Tags: java

I wanted to do some testing on a .jar I have (do not have the source). In previous versions of this .jar, I have decompiled it into .class files, and ran it by typing `java -Xmx512m Client` in terminal.

I know Client.class is the main file,

In manifest.mf, there is this line.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Library: true
Main-Class: Client
```

However when I run my `java -Xmx512m Client`, for some reason it gives me the error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: e (wrong name: E)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Any ideas? Don't understand why the .jar itself seems to be running from the Client.class as its main, but when I decompile it and try to run it manually from the Client main (as I have done in the past) this error is thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `java -Xmx512m Client.java` before it is compiled

Comment: I actually dont have any of the .java files! Usually I decompile it into .class files and make sure I can run it from there. Then I can actually start to reconstruct the .java files and recompile it all to do testing. However I can't run the program from the initial .class files

Comment: NCDFE can be a hard one to crack, but this one is easy.  You have a class file named `e.class`, but inside the declaration is `public class E`.

Comment: Hmm. The manifest file says there are many classes there arent't. Including e.class. There is an "E.class", but it contains "public final class E"

Comment: And also why would an error like that occur, since the .jar runs fine, why wont the decompiled .jar (the .class files)

Comment: It could have to do with the file system that is being used.  Some support mixed case and some don't.

Comment: And when you access through the JAR, that is a different file system too.

Comment: Probably the manifest is being consulted, the loader told to load "e.class", the loader finding "E.class" but being blind to the case difference, and then the wrong class name is found inside.

Comment: So perhaps I should remove all the unused classes from the manifest? I'll give that a shot. Edit: I removed e.class from the manifest.mf to no effect.